# sql sub query returns "Every derived table must have its own alias"

Tags: mysql, sql, runtime-error

I executed this query in my server and got

```
$query1="select clients.name AS client,
packages.pick AS pick,
packages.drop AS `drop`,
packages.created AS created,
packages.status AS status,
packages.id AS id,
packages.name AS package
 from  (packages join clients on(clients.id = packages.client_id))";

$result = $mysqli->query("select count(*) as num from ($query1)");
```

And i got the above error, any idea what is causing the error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Gotta name the subquery:

```
from ($query1) as SubQueryAlias
```

Comment: hello, thanks fo the quick response, how do i access the subquery in code?

Comment: It's not required to actually use the name, but you must give it.  Like `$mysqli->query("select count(*) as num from ($query1) as SubQueryAlias");`